# how to get duration of video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I write this command in commandPrompt but that can not get Duration

> ffmpeg  -i d:\12.flv 2>&1 | grep \"Duration\"

I have this error
'grep ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable programe or batch file
What is problem?

Comment: Also see [How to get video duration in seconds?](http://superuser.com/a/945604/110524) for more examples.

Answer (score 3):

best way I have found is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ext 2>&1 | find "Duration"
```

now, that gives you the duration start and bitrate line.
hope this helps.